# TYPO3 6.2 image crop extension

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I'm looking for an extension in TYPO3 6.2 which does basically the same as the build-in image manipulation feature in TYPO3 7.

So far i had a look on following extensions:

- k23_imagecrop - works, but only usable in filelist module and you cant see any pixel values
- image_crop - no graphical ui
- nwt_imagecrop - no graphical ui

Has anybody a good solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing more. Please think about upgrading!